# RemoteIpAddress in container

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, docker-compose

I was curious if anyone has ran into this problem. Specifically within the Asp world. It seems that docker forwards request to the docker container and it appears as though every request coming in is coming from the same IP address(its a docker ip address ex: 172.x.x.x)

I've seen some fixes as far as using host mode networking. But this doesnt work in an azure container app service.(They enforce bridge mode to my knowledge, And only allow binding on port 80)

I've submitted a bug [report](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1309) to the docker team but I havent received reply.

The given container is apart of a microservice which uses Ocelot to bind downstream and upstream requests to a given service. However this doesnt really matter as the issue occurs even within a singular docker container.

Answer (score 0):

To revisit this post. I will say i never really found an answer for this. But for those of you that are working with azure, A decent workaround you should know is that Azure will forward the ip of the request in a separate header `X-Client-IP`

That will exist in production environments so as long as your gateway will forward that header you can still obtain an ip address.